# What's a word combining appease/placate and encourage?

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a word in the back of my mind that I just can't quite bring to the surface. It is generally used with negative connotations and it means something along the lines of appeasing/placating/pacifying someone to the point of encouraging bad behaviour.

Edit:

A sample sentence:

> Stop [word]ing Clive, he's just going to get worse.

Comment: @user405662, don't think it's that. It's a longer word.

Comment: @KillingTime ok done

Comment: _spoiling_?....

Comment: @user405662 that would work as well to be honest! But it's more "posh" sounding. I feel like it ends in -ating, like facilitating (which I just can't get out of my head). I am not massively confident of that, though.

Comment: _mollycoddle_, then? It sure is "posh"-sounding.

Comment: @user405662 that could be it but I did think of it before asking the question and it didn't feel like whatever is in the back of my head.

Comment: 'Encouraging' works here. 'Don't encourage him' almost always has the implication that the encouraged activity is undesirable. // You might be thinking of 'condone', but behaviours / actions are condoned.

Comment: Maybe *indulging*, which is often used with a similar sense to *spoiling*?

Comment: @Stuart - That's it! Thank you. I can't believe I couldn't think of that word!!

Comment: @Stuart F An answer? Probably ELU rather than ELL, this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Indulging** or **overindulging** a child refers to giving them too much of what they want so they don't learn the necessary life lessons: dealing with disappointment, learning to wait, saving up, learning to share, feeling and expressing gratitude, and more. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indulge) gives as one of the meanings of "indulge": "to treat with excessive leniency, generosity, or consideration", and it's the word "excessive" that is key.

[According to psychology professor David Bredehoft](https://www.inquirer.com/philly/blogs/healthy_kids/Why-overindulging-your-kids-can-lead-to-lifelong-harm.html), it's a form of child neglect because it hampers their development, and produces adults who overeat and drink, are always in debt, can't follow rules, and are never satisfied. There is a [lot of parenting advice](https://lifestyle.livemint.com/relationships/raising-parents/the-science-of-indulging-one-s-children-111608530915405.html) on how to reward children in a healthy way and not (over)indulge them.

Answer (score 0):

The verb "*to condone*" is close  to what is needed, but the encouraging is not part of the meaning, it is just a natural  result of tolerating the given objectionable behaviour.

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/condone) If someone condones behaviour that is morally wrong, they accept it and allow it to happen.

Dictionary definitions often do not mention that people can be condoned, only bad behaviour; however, numerous examples can be found in which  a person is the referent of the  object.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/condone)
[lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/condone)
[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/condone)
[OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/condone?q=condone) (This dictionary mentions the construction "condone (somebody) something".)

([ref. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Jawaharlal_Nehru/_nUeAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22condone+him%22&dq=%22condone+him%22&printsec=frontcover)) On the other hand, he grew fond of his mother who, he felt, would condone him everything.

([ref. 2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Pulpsmith/oWJRAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22condone+him%22&dq=%22condone+him%22&printsec=frontcover)) But we were insignificant to him, except for a laugh. And everybody else in town was the same to him: good for a laugh, which was maybe why I could condone him. He treated everybody with the same contempt. He was the least real of all.

([ref. 3](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Daily_Report_West_Europe/jCK-Nz5XvMUC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22condone+him%22&dq=%22condone+him%22&printsec=frontcover)) If you will not sack him, you condone him, and your government remains in shambles for as long as he remains a member.